# Can I have different DPI-settings for fonts on different monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, fonts, xorg, xfce4, fontconfig

I replaced one of my monitors by one with much higher resolution. Its physical dimensions are bigger too, but not as much bigger as the resolution -- so each pixel became quite a bit smaller.

To address this, I increased the DPI setting from 90 to 120 (using the Xfce4-provided configuration widget), but that's a bit too large for the remaining older monitors on my desk.

Hence the question, can it be set differently for each one? And, if it can be, *how* -- the Xfce4 tool  seems to set it for the entire desktop...